# Xpages ACL entry works on web but not client

Tags: xpages

I have an XPage that I want to restrict access to. So in the ACL property I wrote the following code:

```
        <xp:this.acl>
            <xp:acl>
                <xp:this.entries>
                    <xp:aclEntry name="TSC Time Tracking Administrators"
                        right="EDITOR" type="GROUP" fullName="Administrator">
                    </xp:aclEntry>
                </xp:this.entries>
            </xp:acl>
        </xp:this.acl>
```

This code works on the web - I receive an authentication challenge - but on the client I get a 401 error with "You do not have sufficient authorization to perform this operation"

I think this must be a bug in the client. I am running 9.0.1.

Does anybody know if this is a bug or if there is a work around?

Comment: I don't think this is a bug, because in the client you are already authenticated. Are you in this group? Is "constistent acl" activated?

Comment: Agree -this is correct behaviour given you're not already logged in via the Web. If you were, and tried this page, then you'd get a 'not authorised' message after first being asked for username/password whcih IS authorised. I guess the difference is that the Notes client doesn't do that; it just alets you straight away. Regards a workaround : can you say what you'd like to achieve ?